# Reconnect to erlang node

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

A have two nodes: A and B. A monitors B and B monitors A. When one of the node restarts it tries to connect to second node. Question is how to make reconnection to node if ethernet connection between two computers with nodes is failed and then restored.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the nodes using [erlang:monitor_node](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#monitor_node-2) which detects only the nodedown of already connected node. Instead of this you can use [net_kernel:monitor_nodes](http://erlang.org/doc/man/net_kernel.html#monitor_nodes-2) where in even the node status change is tracked. So the monitoring process can receive nodedown message with reason (for connection close or actual node down) which can be handled. nodeup message is received whenever the connection is established.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for [net_kernel:connect_node/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/net_kernel.html#connect_node-1) or [net_adm:ping/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/net_adm.html#ping-1).